# Way to ensure that current page is the last one with Spring Data Paging

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to optimize the number of aggregation requests for my service using Spring Data.

Is there a legit way to find out that the page returned by repository method like this:

```
List<Place> findByVisitorsUid(String uid, Pageable pageable);
```

requested with `PageRequest` like this:

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(currentPage, pageSize);
```

is actually the **last** page?

In other words, is there a way to ensure that there are no more data chunks to be returned with current page request params like fixed page size etc.,
**except** making extra repository request with incremented page index?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A repository method that accepts a `Pageable` argument should return a `org.springframework.data.domain.Page` instead of a `List`. `Page` has two properties - `getNumber()` and `getTotalPages()`. Comparing the two is sufficient to know if the returned page is the last page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to manish I'm pretty sure now that if you're pursuing the goal described in question than repository method should return `Page` instead of `List` (though it's not necessary for simple paging functionality).